# PonyORM on an existing table

Tags: python, ponyorm

Is there any way to use PonyORM for an existing database?

I have a table `Test` in my db and I want to define an Entity `Test` to connect to that table, I tried to use `_table_ = 'Test'` and `__table_name__ = 'Test'` like:

```
class Test(db.Entity):
    __table_name__ = 'Test'
```

This allowed me to execute queries on table `Test`, but I can't access table columns via Entity attributes (I guess because it does not load them from db automatically).

For example, when I try to create a new instance of `Test`, I get:

```
Test(my_attr = 'Hello')

>>> TypeError: Unknown attribute 'my_attr'
```

I'm working on a *Database First* designed project and the database is changing constantly, so keep redefining columns in Entities seems like a bad solution.

Comment: I ended up using the bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must write columns to class. This way it can correctly link your database table to the class.

For example

```
class Test(db.Entity):
    __table_name__ = 'Test'

    my_attr = Optional(str)
```